Upgrading Node.js Add-on with cppgraphqlgen to Support Version 4.5.8
I am working on a Node.js add-on using cppgraphqlgen and recently upgraded from version 3.6.0 to the latest version 4.5.8. The existing implementation involves a basic GraphQL schema and MockData to return a simple greet message, "Hello World". The goal of this question:

To update the add-on to work seamlessly with cppgraphqlgen version
4.5.8.

Current Setup
The source files involved in the project are:

main.cpp
GreetImpl.h
GreetImpl.cpp
schema.greet.graphql
binding.gyp

The GreetImpl.cpp implementation currently handles a simple greet message using cppgraphqlgen version 3.6.0, but I am encountering issues when upgrading to version 4.5.8.
The source code is compiled using node-gyp. Below is the structure of the desired functionality:

Node.js Add-on Operations

The add-on should support the following operations:

startService()
stopService()
fetchQuery(query: string): string

Example Usage in Node.js
Here is how the add-on is utilized in a Node.js environment:
    //index.js

    const addon = require('./build/Release/greet.node');
    
    addon.startService();
    console.log(addon.fetchQuery(`
    { 
        hello {
            greet
        }
        greetmsg 
    }
    `, '', ''))
    addon.stopService();

Key Questions:

Upgrading to cppgraphqlgen 4.5.8:


What changes are required to update GreetImpl.cpp to support the new version?
Are there any specific compatibility concerns or breaking changes in version 4.5.8 compared to 3.6.0?


Compilation with node-gyp:


Are there any additional configurations required in binding.gyp to support the changes in cppgraphqlgen 4.5.8?

Supporting Files:
Here are the project files for reference:

github project URL greet-cppgraphqlgen-node
main.cpp 
GreetImpl.h 
GreetImpl.cpp 
schema.greet.graphql 
binding.gyp 


"do my work for me" is not a useful question for StackOverflow. Please edit your question and narrow it down to a single, concrete problem.
